# jCrop is not being called.

Tags: jquery, jcrop

jQuery('#imgCrop').Jcrop() is not being called. Am I referencing jCrop correctly?
Please refer to my links for my VS2010 screenshots. Thanks!

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<link href="Scripts/jCrop-v0.9.9/css/jquery.Jcrop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/jCrop-v0.9.9/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jCrop-v0.9.9/js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jCrop-v0.9.9/js/jquery.Jcrop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery('#imgCrop').Jcrop({
            onSelect: storeCoords
        });
    });

    function storeCoords(c) {

        jQuery('#X').val(c.x);
        jQuery('#Y').val(c.y);
        jQuery('#W').val(c.w);
        jQuery('#H').val(c.h);
    };
</script>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSJqw.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVdPP.png

Comment: for one, you probably don't need both the full and minimized versions of Jcrop.js.  It's possible that loading it twice might cause issues (although unlikely).

Comment: Found the solution: [HERE](http://forums.asp.net/t/1553510.aspx/1?jQuery+with+Master+Pages)

Comment: It would generally help others if you could include the solution on here (in the event of the other website not being available for example)

Comment: If imgCrop is server side control and this function is placed in aspx page. Code will change this way

jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
        jQuery('#<%= imgCrop.ClientID%>').Jcrop({  
          onSelect: storeCoords  
        });  
      });

Comment: Another tutorial suggested this: setTimeout("$('imgEdit').JCrop();",1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remove the extraneous jcrop include from the header?  You only need to include Jcrop once; in your example you're pulling in both the full and minimized versions.  Instinct says the 2nd include would just overwrite the first in this case, but it doesn't hurt to check.

Have you tried sending the function inline?  Or calling `Jcrop()` without arguments?  (to see if the function is causing issue).

```
jQuery.Jcrop('#imgCrop', {
    onSelect: function (c) {
        jQuery('#X').val(c.x);
        jQuery('#Y').val(c.y);
        jQuery('#W').val(c.w);
        jQuery('#H').val(c.h);
    }
});
```

I'm grasping at straws a bit here because otherwise it looks like it should work.  I'm not an ASP developer so I can't tell if your issue exists there.

Comment: Didn't work. Here is a link to my web app in VS2010:             [link](http://www.filefactory.com/file/cde6727/n/WebApplication2.zip )